# Otimização no código VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Tenho duas planilhas, ambas possuem o mesmo cabeçalho, com 77 colunas. Para teste coloquei 4 linhas com dados preenchidos em uma das tabelas. Na tabela com os dados preenchidos, tenho o botão com a macro, para copiar esses dados para a planilha que possue somente o cabeçalho, porém para que essa macro finalize a cópia para a outra planilha demora aproximadamente 30 minutos. Como a finalidade é otimizar um processo manual, no qual haverá muito mais que 4 linhas de dados preenchidas, a macro se tornará inviável desta forma. Existe uma forma de otimizar o código e reduzir esse tempo ? O código é o seguinte:

```
Sub Percorre()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim contador, col As Integer
Dim valor, PastaAtual, NomeDoArquivo, NomeCompletoDoArquivo As String
Dim Busca As Range
Dim RangeFrom As Range
Dim RangeTo As Range
Dim Busca_col As Integer
Dim WorkBookNovo As Workbook

contador = 0
col = 1


ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Aspiradores").Activate
PastaAtual = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
NomeDoArquivo = "teste.xlsx"
NomeCompletoDoArquivo = PastaAtual + "\" + NomeDoArquivo
Set WorkBookNovo = Workbooks.Open(NomeCompletoDoArquivo)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Aspiradores").Activate

Do While Cells(2, col).Value <> ""

    Cells(2, col).Select
    valor = Cells(2, col).Value

    Columns(col).Select
    numRows = Selection.Rows.Count
    Selection.Resize(numRows - 1).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Set RangeFrom = Selection

    WorkBookNovo.Activate
    Set Busca = WorkBookNovo.Application.Cells.Find(What:=valor, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Busca.Activate
    Busca_col = Busca.Column
    WorkBookNovo.ActiveSheet.Columns(Busca_col).Select
    numRows = Selection.Rows.Count
    Selection.Resize(numRows - 1).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.Value = RangeFrom.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Aspiradores").Activate
    contador = contador + 1
    col = col + 1
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Pra que você usa `WorkBookNovo.Application.Cells.Find`? Essa chamada certamente custa bastante tempo, e se você está simplesmente copiando dados de uma planilha pra outra iterando sobre as células essa busca deveria ser desnecessária. Não? Aliás, também é desnecessariamente custoso ficar selecionando as células (isto é, fazer `<qualquer célula>.Select`), se você pega o conteúdo diretamente da célula. Você depurou o código? Fez o mesmo teste com, digamos, apenas 4 colunas pra facilitar o seu entendimento? Com uma depuração você descobre onde exatamente tá demorando mais.

Comment: De todas as formas é difícil te ajudar sem ter que entender *exatamente* o seu código e o uso dele. Eu sugiro que você edite a questão e forneça um exemplo ilustrativo dos dados (se possível, com apenas 4 ou 5 colunas) e explique exatamente o que você está tentando fazer. Esse código parece ter sido construído em partes com o gerador de macros, e essa não é a melhor abordagem (esse gerador só serve, na prática, pra se aprender VBA).

Comment: Obrigada Luiz. Então, a finalidade do comando find é encontrar a coluna com o mesmo indice na outra planilha, já que as colunas estão em ordens diferentes, exemplo: A coluna "Nome" é A na planilha 1 e E na planilha 2. Eu já usei o depurador e é exatamente no comando find que mais demora. Como sou iniciante, o que eu gostaria é saber se existe recursos que possam otimizar o tempo de execução desse código. Ele copia tudo certinho, como eu preciso, porém o tempo é muito longo e trava tudo, com frequência durante a execução.

Comment: Se as colunas, apesar de estarem diferentes, não mudam frequentemente (isto é, se o usuário não as rearranja), o melhor a fazer e ter uma tabela de-para que dado o nome da coluna na planilha A retorna a coluna dela na planilha B e eliminar essa função de busca. Vc resolve a possibilidade do usuário mudar a ordem das colunas travando a planilha.

Answer (score 2):

Para qualquer trabalho de otimização de código, uma das ações básicas é a redução máxima de ações (e linhas). Uma das principais ações que podem ser descartadas são as seleções de objetos e intervalos (o bendito ".Select", bem comum quando vc grava macros). Logo temos resultados idênticos para as seguintes linhas de códigos:

```
'Código sem otimizar
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy

'Código otimizado
    Range("A1").Copy
```

Ou , num aplicado ao seu código:

```
'Código sem otimizar
    Columns(col).Select
    numRows = Selection.Rows.Count

'Código otimizado
    numRows = Columns(col).Rows.Count
```

Outra coisa: já que vc tem dua matrizes com npumero fixo de colunas (77), por que você não copia tudo de uma vez, em vez de repetir a ação coluna a coluna? Além disso, vc está trabalhando com um intervalo muito grande de células (da linha 2 até a 1.048.576)... tem necessidade disso? De qualquer forma, sugiro que você.

Assim, eu escreveria todo o seu código da seguinte forma:

```
Sub Percorre()

'Desabilitar recursos desnecessários
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Dimensionar variáveis
    Dim wsOrig, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim numRows As Long
    Dim PastaAtual, NomeDoArquivo, NomeCompletoDoArquivo, valor As String
    Dim Busca, RangeFrom, RangeTo As Range

'Declarar variáveis na planilha corrente
    Set wsOrig = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Aspiradores")
    wsOrig.Activate
    'contar apenas o total de linhas com valor. Caso não haja valor na célula "A1", somar (+1)
    numRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
    Set RangeFrom = Range(Cells(2, 1).Value, Cells(numRows, 77))
    valor = RangeFrom.Cells(1).Value

'Abrir planilha destino e declarar variáveis
    PastaAtual = ThisWorkbook.Path
    NomeDoArquivo = "teste.xlsx"
    NomeCompletoDoArquivo = PastaAtual & "\" & NomeDoArquivo
    Set wsDest = Workbooks.Open(NomeCompletoDoArquivo).ActiveSheet
    wsDest.Activate
    'Encontrar endereço da célula buscada
    Set Busca = Cells.Find(What:=valor, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Address
    Set RangeTo = Range(Busca, Busca.Offset(numRows, 77))
    RangeTo.Value = RangeFrom.Value

'Restaurar recursos desabilitados
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso as colunas estejam em ordems diferentes, o código teria que fazer um loop mesmo, de coluna em coluna:

```
Sub Percorre()

'Desabilitar recursos desnecessários
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Dimensionar variáveis
    Dim wsOrig, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim numRows As Long
    Dim PastaAtual, NomeDoArquivo, NomeCompletoDoArquivo, valor As String
    Dim Busca, RangeFrom, RangeTo As Range

'Declarar variáveis na planilha corrente
    Set wsOrig = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Aspiradores")
    wsOrig.Activate
    'contar apenas o total de linhas com valor. Caso não haja valor na célula "A1", somar (+1)
    numRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
    Set RangeFrom = wsOrig.Range(Cells(2, 1).Value, Cells(numRows, 77))

'Abrir planilha destino e declarar variáveis
    PastaAtual = ThisWorkbook.Path
    NomeDoArquivo = "teste.xlsx"
    NomeCompletoDoArquivo = PastaAtual & "\" & NomeDoArquivo
    Set wsDest = Workbooks.Open(NomeCompletoDoArquivo).ActiveSheet
    wsDest.Activate
    wsDest.Cells(1, 1).Select

'Loop para cópia de colunas 1 a 1
    Dim n As Integer: n = 1
    Do While RangeFrom.Cells(1, n) <> vbNullString
        valor = RangeFrom.Cells(1, n).Value
        Set Busca = Cells.Find(What:=valor, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Address
        Set RangeTo = Range(Busca, Busca.Offset(RangeFrom.Rows.Count - 1, 0))
        RangeTo.Value = RangeFrom.Columns(n).Value
        n = n + 1
        Loop

'Restaurar recursos desabilitados
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```